# Как правильно понимать P из CAP теоремы на примерах?

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, микросервисы

На вики:

> The system continues to operate despite an arbitrary number of
> messages being dropped (or delayed) by the network between nodes.

1. Не понятно что такое operate в данном случае. Любое функционирование системы? CA системы вообще  не будут взаимодействовать с клиентом/функционировать после разрыва связи или могут просто снизить сервис который они предоставляют?
2. Встречал [пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-Yaq8AHlFA) с 2 банкоматами. Если связь между банкоматами пропадает, то нужно выбирать A или С при обслуживании клиентов. Какая это система AC, PA, PC? В моем понимании это или PA или PC система. Так как при обрыве связи, система все еще в целом функционирует(о чем размышлял на первом пункте). Но если это PA или PC система, то почему при отсутствии сбоев в сети она одновременно может иметь свойства A и С?
3. Есть пример CA систем?
   С особенностями баз данных которые есть на рынке не знаком, такие примеры не очень будут полезны без подробного обьяснения каждой мелочи. Примеры из 1 узла похоже тут не применимы, так как CAP именно про распределенные системы.
   Была [статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/130577/), где приводили пример консистентной и доступной системы, вроде как CA:

> Кажется, всё отлично уже который день. Ваша система согласована. Всё
> работает, даже если кто-то из вас не может выйти на работу. Но что
> выйдет, если вы оба вышли на работу, но один из вас не может обновить
> информацию другого? Помните, как вы будили свою жену с очередным
> Гениальнейшим Бредом? Что, если ваша жена решится принимать звонки, но
> будет слишком обижена на вас и решит не разговаривать с вами весь
> день? Весь ваш бизнес опять превратится в тыкву! Ваша идея до сих пор
> хороша за её согласованность и доступность, но очень чувствительна к
> разделению коммуникаций! Вы конечно, можете не принимать ни одного
> звонка, пока вы в ссоре, но тогда ваша система будет недоступна всё
> это время…

Но тут так же есть выбор между A и С при разрыве связи между узлами.  Зачем тогда вообще думать о P, если у системы CA есть такой выбор? Или CA значит что при разрыве связи нет возможности выбирать компромис (С или A), а просто будет отдавать ошибку на запрос (что похоже на PC)?